# Syntax error when trying to pass second argument to JS function

Tags: javascript, android, webview

The following works:

```
loadUrl("javascript:HtmlViewer.showHTML" + "('<html>'+document.forms[0].elements['MYHiddenValue'].value+'</html>', 'blah');");
```

The following:

```
loadUrl("javascript:HtmlViewer.showHTML" + "('<html>'+document.forms[0].elements['MYHiddenValue'].value+'</html>', 'document.forms[0].elements['MYHiddenValue'].value');");
```

or

```
loadUrl("javascript:HtmlViewer.showHTML" + "('<html>'+document.forms[0].elements['MYHiddenValue'].value+'</html>', 'document.forms[0].elements['MYSecondHiddenValue'].value');");`
```

Gives:

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list", source:  (1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've got weird characters in that code, and in particular there are some single-quotes that aren't single-quote characters (around the "MYHiddenValue" strings).

Comment: @Pointy:That was a copy/paste issue. Fixed OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the problem.  In your first (working) example,

```
loadUrl("javascript:HtmlViewer.showHTML" + "('<html>'+document.forms[0].elements[’MYHiddenValue’].value+'</html>', 'blah');");
```

the second embedded parameter 'blah' does not have any internal quotes.  However, in your first non-working example,

```
loadUrl("javascript:HtmlViewer.showHTML" + "('<html>'+document.forms[0].elements[’MYHiddenValue’].value+'</html>', 'document.forms[0].elements[’MYHiddenValue’].value');");
```

there is an embedded quote in a section of the parameter that should be evaluated.  The following sub-string (found in both examples has a string ('') concatenated with code that evaluates to a string concatenated with another string, the closing HTML tag.

```
'<html>'+document.forms[0].elements[’MYHiddenValue’].value+'</html>'
```

In the non-working second example,

```
 'document.forms[0].elements[’MYHiddenValue’].value'
```

You have a string that I believe just needs to be evaluated.  JavaScript is seeing this as a string like as below, but this is not what you want.

```
 'document.forms[0].elements[’
```

I believe if you remove the outer pair of single-quote marks in this non-working example, it will work, as the code will evaluate.  If you need it to just be a string, then you need to escape the inner single-quote marks as in

```
 'document.forms[0].elements[\'MYHiddenValue\'].value'
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace all ’ characters with '

(Copy /  paste from here as they look like each other)

**Edit after the comment from OP below.**

First failing command :

```
loadUrl("javascript:HtmlViewer.showHTML" + "('<html>'+document.forms[0].elements['MYHiddenValue'].value+'</html>', 'document.forms[0].elements['MYHiddenValue'].value');");
```

This has a pair of single quotes which will cause a syntax error when the line executed and produced the string. It should produce an escaped pair of single quotes so the line should contain an 'escaped' backslash:

```
loadUrl("javascript:HtmlViewer.showHTML" + "('<html>'+document.forms[0].elements['MYHiddenValue'].value+'</html>', 'document.forms[0].elements[\\'MYHiddenValue\\'].value');");
```

Second option would be using double quotes and escaping each with a single backslash at the first stage like :

```
loadUrl("javascript:HtmlViewer.showHTML" + "('<html>'+document.forms[0].elements['MYHiddenValue'].value+'</html>', 'document.forms[0].elements[\"MYHiddenValue\"].value');");
```

Second command has also a similar error on 'MYSecondHiddenValue'.

The reason that first command is not failing is that it is building the html string by adding three separate strings which is not causing a quote issue.

But this also makes the three commands differ each other. First command adds **the value of** document.forms[0].elements['MYHiddenValue'] and the other two adds **the string** "document.forms[0].elements...value". So we don't know which one is correct without knowing what showHTML() does exactly.

Comment: That was a copy/paste issue. Fixed OP

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking at your code right now, I can see that

```
loadUrl("javascript:HtmlViewer.showHTML" + "('<html>'+document.forms[0].elements[’MYHiddenValue’].value+'</html>', 'document.forms[0].elements[’MYHiddenValue’].value');");
```

Is really one big string, (or two that are concatinated), try changing it to:

```
loadUrl("javascript:HtmlViewer.showHTML" + "('<html>'+document.forms[0].elements[’MYHiddenValue’].value+'</html>'", "'document.forms[0].elements[’MYHiddenValue’].value');");
```

perhaps?